# Посоветуйте где есть открытый код формы регистрации?

Tags: java, android, реестр

Хочу сделать регистрацию в приложении... Наверняка уже есть проверенные рабочие коды форм регистрации, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если Вам что-то необходимо и Вы знаете что это, по идее, уже реализовали до Вас, идите на [github.com](https://github.com/) и там оно должно быть.

К примеру, первая в поиске: [Android authorization registration system](https://github.com/tarzak/Android-authorization-registration-system)
[image: Регистрация]

Если не подходит - поищите и среди более сотни результатов точно найдете.

Comment: Подскажите, а для чего вам авторизация в приложении? У вас клиент-серверное приложение? Если работаешь свеб сервисами - то не вопрос, а если нет! Вот тоже подумываю может сделать авторизацию тоже...